# Fullcalendar Multiday events place on wrong by one day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

> I used this Full calendar for assign employee task. and here its
>   multiday events not dragging to multi-day. its dragged and converted
>   in one-day Event here its MySQL database connected to binding events.
>   So I need help to figure out where I was wrong. My Code is as below.

Events have arrived from database like
id,title,start,end,allDay

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: "http://localhost:8888/calendar/events.php",
                eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    }
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                    if (title) {
                        var start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
                        var end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8888/calendar/add_events.php',
                            data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&url=' + url,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (json) {
                                alert('Added Successfully');
                            }
                        });
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay

                                },
                                true 
                                );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
                editable: true,
                eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    var start = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
                    var end = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/calendar/update_events.php',
                        data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventResize: function (event) {
                    var start = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
                    var end = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8888/calendar/update_events.php',
                        data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventClick: function (event) {
                    var decision = confirm("Do you really want to do that?");
                    if (decision) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://localhost:8888/calendar/delete_events.php",
                            data: "&id=" + event.id
                        });
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Thank You**
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I drag to create a new multi-day event, it's created multi-day. If I drag an existing event wider to multiple days, it's rendered as multiple-days. Are you saying that it gets saved wrongly to the database? If so, you'd have to show the code for that. P.S. I would not construct your ajax data manually like that - it's brittle and prone to encoding errors. Instead specify "data" as a JSON object and jQuery will encode it automatically for you. e.g. `data: { "title": title, "start": start, "end": end, "url": url }`

Comment: Thank You Sir For Your reply

Comment: Happy to try and help. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: no sir @ADyson , i will make my custom calendar for this now. Same like Deputy